# Log external process signals via command line

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, posix

Is there any way to monitor several processed by related PID and log all the process signal events?

Example input:
PID=10

Command:
here some command with PID=10

Example expected output:
timestamp \t 2 (=SIGINT)
timestamp \t 9 (=SIGKILL)

The format is irrelevant, the processes should be watch the PID all the time, important is to not miss any signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to track all signals a selection of processes receives:

```
sudo strace -e signal=all -tt -f -p 27486 -p 27491 -p 27496
```

Multiple processes can be monitored (use `-p PID` multiple times) and some signals can even be not tracked (for example `-e 'signal=!SIGINT'` will not track `SIGINT`). Timestamp with microsecond precision is included with `-tt` and children processes (and threads) are included with `-f`. Root privileges are required.

Sample output (which you can easily post-process with `awk`, for example):

```
strace: Process 27486 attached
strace: Process 27491 attached
strace: Process 27496 attached
[pid 27496] 20:54:50.917454 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 27491] 20:54:50.917480 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 27486] 20:54:50.917486 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
[pid 27486] 20:55:03.044313 --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=26964, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 27486] 20:55:03.044624 +++ killed by SIGHUP +++
[pid 27491] 20:55:16.405891 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
20:55:45.270789 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
20:55:45.270929 --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=26964, si_uid=1000} ---
20:55:45.271224 +++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

(Note that if only one process is monitored, or when all are killed except one, the line is not prefixed with PID, but PID can also be recovered from `si_pid`.)

Comment: I tested the strace and for my purpose is makes the app about 10x slower. The overhead is even if some event filter is applied. The strace has also problems with SIGCONT and SIGSTOP. Do you know any other solution, maybe via `perf`?

Comment: You can try [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) (on Debian/Ubuntu:  `sudo apt-get install sysdig`), a fantastic monitoring tool running as a kernel module (with very small overhead), able to filter events by type, PID, and many other parameters.

Comment: I am acepting your answer. The targetted use was to monitor all of our company processes across several machines. It seems there is no way to watch the processed externally for kill signals only without any major impact on other syscalls.

Comment: Have you tried with `sysdig`? I believe it shouldn't have much impact on performance (since it's running as a kernel module), although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it incl. other tools like `perf`. Even if only kill signals were traced the overhead was significant (about 5x for dd with bs=1).

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the problem (overhead) is in processing the event messages those tools generate. I think you can script `sysdig` with Lua, which in combination with restrictive filtering (to reduce the number of events to a minimum), could probably reduce that overhead significantly.

Comment: `strace -e signal=all` seems can't tell `SIGKILL` sender